# convert xml to string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a variable containing XML tags 
How to display this variable at the HTML page In one row of the table as a string with jquery

Comment: "<td colspan='3'><![CDATA["+messageBody_res+"]]></td>" ... 
is fail...
Again display to the state XML tag ...
is not text...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you've attempted, how you're getting the XML; in other words, a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide us with some code

Answer (score 0):

**    I found this on Stackoverflow. Please try if it helps- :)**

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>

function xmlToString(xmlData) { 

    var xmlString;
    //IE
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlString = xmlData.xml;
    }
    // code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
    else{
        xmlString = (new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(xmlData);
    }
    return xmlString;
}   

</script>
```

Comment: xmlData is    xml.find('messageBody_req').text() contains   messageBody_req = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas

Answer (score 0):

the best solution:

function displayXml(str) {
    var htmlString = String(str).replace(/&/g, '&').replace(//g, '>').replace(/"/g, '"');
    return htmlString;

}